# Dataframe Insert Labels if filename starts with a 'b'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe and give a lable to each file, based on the first letter of the filename:

This is where I created the dataframe, which works out fine:

```
[IN]
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep="\t", names=['file', 'text', 'label'], header=None, engine='python')
texts = df['text'].values.astype("U")

print(df)
```

```
[OUT]
           file                                               text  label
0     b_001.txt  Ad sales boost Time Warner profitQuarterly pro...    NaN
1     b_002.txt  Dollar gains on Greenspan speechThe dollar has...    NaN
2     b_003.txt  Yukos unit buyer faces loan claimThe owners of...    NaN
3     b_004.txt  High fuel prices hit BA's profitsBritish Airwa...    NaN
4     b_005.txt  Pernod takeover talk lifts DomecqShares in UK ...    NaN
...         ...                                                ...    ...
2220  t_397.txt  BT program to beat dialler scamsBT is introduc...    NaN
2221  t_398.txt  Spam e-mails tempt net shoppersComputer users ...    NaN
2222  t_399.txt  Be careful how you codeA new European directiv...    NaN
2223  t_400.txt  US cyber security chief resignsThe man making ...    NaN
2224  t_401.txt  Losing yourself in online gamingOnline role pl...    NaN
```

Now I want to insert labels based on the filename

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['file'].startswith('b'):
        row['label'] = 0
    elif row['file'].startswith('e'):
        row['label'] = 1
    elif row['file'].startswith('p'):
        row['label'] = 2
    elif row['file'].startswith('s'):
        row['label'] = 3
    else:
        row['label'] = 4

print(df)
```

```
[OUT]
           file                                               text  label
0     b_001.txt  Ad sales boost Time Warner profitQuarterly pro...      4
1     b_002.txt  Dollar gains on Greenspan speechThe dollar has...      4
2     b_003.txt  Yukos unit buyer faces loan claimThe owners of...      4
3     b_004.txt  High fuel prices hit BA's profitsBritish Airwa...      4
4     b_005.txt  Pernod takeover talk lifts DomecqShares in UK ...      4
...         ...                                                ...    ...
2220  t_397.txt  BT program to beat dialler scamsBT is introduc...      4
2221  t_398.txt  Spam e-mails tempt net shoppersComputer users ...      4
2222  t_399.txt  Be careful how you codeA new European directiv...      4
2223  t_400.txt  US cyber security chief resignsThe man making ...      4
2224  t_401.txt  Losing yourself in online gamingOnline role pl...      4
```

As you can see, every row got the label 4. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

instead of for loop, you can use map to assign the values to the label

```
# create a dictionary of key: value map
d={'b':0,'e':1,'p':2,'s':3}
else_val=4

#take the first character from the filename, and map using dictionary
# null values (else condition) will be 4
df['file'].str[:1].map(d).fillna(else_val).astype(int)
```

```
        file    text    label
0   0   b_001.txt   Ad sales boost Time Warner profitQuarterly pro...   0
1   1   b_002.txt   Dollar gains on Greenspan speechThe dollar has...   0
2   2   b_003.txt   Yukos unit buyer faces loan claimThe owners of...   0
3   3   b_004.txt   High fuel prices hit BA's profitsBritish Airwa...   0
4   4   b_005.txt   Pernod takeover talk lifts DomecqShares in UK ...   0
5   2220    t_397.txt   BT program to beat dialler scamsBT is introduc...   4
6   2221    t_398.txt   Spam e-mails tempt net shoppersComputer users ...   4
7   2222    t_399.txt   Be careful how you codeA new European directiv...   4
8   2223    t_400.txt   US cyber security chief resignsThe man making ...   4
9   2224    t_401.txt   Losing yourself in online gamingOnline role pl...   4
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) usage of `iterrows()` to modify data frame not guaranteed work in all cases beacuse it is not preserve dtype accross rows and etc...

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not
> guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
> iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
> effect.

Therefore do instead as follows.

```
 def label():
        if row['file'].startswith('b'):
            return 0
        elif row['file'].startswith('e'):
            return 1
        elif row['file'].startswith('p'):
            return 2
        elif row['file'].startswith('s'):
            return 3
        else:
            return 4

df['label'] = df.apply(lambda row :label(row[0]),axis=1)
```